# Error inflating class com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton

Tags: android, twitter-fabric

I'm trying to use TwitterLoginButton in DialogFragment.

I got error : 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton

Using TwitterLoginButton in Activity class, I got no error.

Please help me.

dialog_auth.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@color/white" android:id="@+id/dialog_auth">

<com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton
    android:id="@+id/twitter_login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

AuthDialog.java

```
public class AuthDialog extends DialogFragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_auth, null);
    return view
}
```

Comment: `TwitterLoginButton NOT SUPPORTED IN DIALOG VIEW `)

Comment: I understand. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is my comment helpful ?

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya Yes, of course. I won't use Dialog but Activity. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in

You can not create Login Button In Dialog .

```
TwitterLoginButton NOT SUPPORTED IN DIALOG VIEW
```